# Is it possible to combine the 'on' and 'click' jquery functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, click, live

Basically I have code which is follows:

```
$('selector').on('click',function(){
    //Do something here
});
$('selector').click(function(){
    //Does exact same thing.    
});
```

Is it possible to combine these? Or would I simply make a function to call from inside both of these bindings?

Apologies if this has been answered, I did check the suggested questions, but didn't find any answers.

Comment: Why do you even have both `.on('click')` and `.click()`? Don't they do the same thing?

Comment: This should help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944293/jquery-liveclick-vs-click

Comment: The .on function is for dynamic elements added onto the page. The click function is for elements which are initially loaded with the page.

Comment: You can just use `on()` for both. There's no need to separate dynamic events from those already on the page.

Comment: why the downvotes? it might be more of a beginner grade question but we all started somewhere. if you live in an ivory tower it pays to know what it's built on.

Comment: Thanks @Juhana - my bad for asking such a silly question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('selector').click()` is just a shortcut to `$('selector').on('click')`

Comment: right answer, you shouldn't try to do something different... or the same in both of them. Just always use `.on`

Comment: it is *now* but until recently `.click()` was a shortcut for `.bind()`. Only since 1.7.x was `.click()` a shortcut for `.on()`. </pedant>

Answer (score 1):

```
$('selector').on('click',function(){ //Do something here });
```

and

```
$('selector').click(function(){ //Does exact same thing.});
```

second one short format of first. use any one. first one is suggested

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, as of jQuery 1.7, `.click()` is merely shorthand for `.on('click')`. If you want, you can therefore save a function call by using `.on('click')` directly.

See jQuery source: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js

Comment: I'm not so sure about it, I've had some problems with dinamically added elements using just click, the event isn't asocciated to the elements, with on('click') I managed to make it work

Answer (score -1):

You can just create a function, and call it from within both callbacks:

```
function doSomething()
{
   alert("something");
}

$('selector').on('click',function(){
    // Do some stuff...

    // Do what should be done by both functions
    doSomething();
});
$('otherselector').click(function(){
    // Do some other stuff...

    // Do what should be done by both functions
    doSomething();   
});
```

**Edit based on the comments**

If both callbacks should do the exact same thing, you can just pass the function as a callback:

```
function doSomething()
{
   alert("something");
}

$('selector').on('click',doSomething);
$('otherselector').click(doSomething);
```

But in that case you could just as well do:

```
$("selector, otherselector").click(function()
{
   alert("something");
});
```

Comment: Why the downvote? I believe OP wants to do the same thing from two different callbacks. The question is not about whether `.on()` and `.click()` is the same thing.

Comment: I didnt downvote but I guess its because they're the SAME event no need to do all this.

Comment: @elclanrs That is only true if you want to do the exact same thing for both callbacks.

Comment: +1 to offset annoying downvotes. however answer isnt perfect - IMO you should point out that using both these events might lead to duplicate function calls if you're not careful (although I notice you thought of that as far as the code goes)

Comment: The OP does want to do the exact same thing. It says so in the question.