# radio button(with click event) not passing the parameter in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have radio buttons embedded in my form as

```
<%= f.radio_button :name_present,true,:class => "namePresent"%>
<%= f.radio_button :name_present,false,:class => "namePresent"%>
```

and my application.js file contains

```
$(".namePresent").live('click',function(e){

     $("#form").submit();
//form is the id of my form_for
 });
```

All parameters are passed in chrome, but in firefox parameter from radio buttons are not passed.

Comment: You are missing `$` in `("#form").submit();`

Comment: Sorry my fault.But it actual code it exists

Comment: Don't put this code in your application.js. create your own .js or better use the .coffee file

Answer (score 2):

I should point out that **live** and **bind** are both deprecated. You can perform both with .**on()**

Try:

```
$(".namePresent").on('click',function(e){

   $("#form").submit();
//form is the id of my form_for
 });
```

Look at the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944293/jquery-liveclick-vs-click) .

Comment: Thanks Vik ...Its working fine on google chrome , but not on firefox and opera. Can there be any other reason for this.(Not tested on IE)

Comment: Are you creating this dom dynamically ? Try this $(".namePresent").unbind('click').bind('click', function (ev){ ....YOUR_CODE });